# Cloud Backup from Network Drive?

Tags: cloud-storage

My company keeps a document repository on a network drive.  I need access to a small subset of directories on that remote drive (maybe 30G or so).  But accessing the drive via VPN when I'm working remotely is unreliable.

I'm willing to buy some cloud storage but I'm not sure how to configure it to include just *some* of the subdirectories on the network drive.  (I know that active backups / syncing will only happen when my laptop is on the intranet and "sees" the network drive, and this is fine.)

Is there a way to set up a local directory structure on my laptop, perhaps using symbolic links, that mirrors *just* the remote drive subdirs I need?  Then I could aim a cloud storage service there to that local directory.  Would this work?

Answer (score 0):

I have been in your situation and I found a solution that certainly helps me accomplish my needs. Backup my files to the cloud and also access/share/recover files anytime. I've tried a couple of them like Carbonite & Mozy Pro (they were okay but not great) but Infrascale did pass the test. You should try contacting them - or even try Intronis.

Comment: My question wasn't about cloud backup; I'm familiar with how that works.  The question was more about how to backup directories from a workplace network drive, and to include only SOME of those directories.  I think that some (all?) cloud backup services, unless you're on the expensive business plan, prohibit network drive backups.  So I was wondering if I could create symbolic links to only the directories I need, have those links "live" on my local drive, and aim the cloud backup software to them.